# How do I fix it 'error: undefined' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When I type '5' and 'asd' in this code, I want it showing 'Error: Not a number.', but it shows 'Error: undefined'. So, what's the problem? I can't find where it is wrong.

```js
function productOf(num1, num2) {
  try {
    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
      alert('This is not a number, please try it again.');
      throw new Error('Not a number.');
    } else {
      return num1 * num2;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.name + ': ' + err.messsage);
  }
}

inputNum1 = window.prompt('Please enter a number: ');
inputNum2 = window.prompt('Please enter your second number: ');

console.log(productOf(inputNum1, inputNum2));
```

Comment: remove the .messsage from err

Comment: Your problem is that your err.message has three `s` instead of two. :)

Comment: Thank you. floor  and  zfrisch. Now I notice where it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simply that your `catch` is logging out `err.messsage` instead of `err.message`. This results in the custom error not being able to be thrown at all.

Simply correcting this as `err.message` instead of `err.messsage` resolves the problem, as is seen in the following:

```js
function productOf(num1, num2) {
  try {
    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
      alert('This is not a number, please try it again.');
      throw new Error('Not a number.');
    } else {
      return num1 * num2;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.name + ': ' + err.message);
  }
}

inputNum1 = window.prompt('Please enter a number: ');
inputNum2 = window.prompt('Please enter your second number: ');

console.log(productOf(inputNum1, inputNum2));
```

Comment: Thank you. I know now. There is a more 's' in my code. ~,~

Comment: Thank you for telling me this. It is my first question on this website. I'm not familiar with rules on this site.

Comment: No problem at all! That's not a rule though; just general practice :) I'd recommend you take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site to familarise yourself with it :)